# Column designator X with topiclongtable

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, topiclongtable

I want to build a topic table in a LaTeX document, and the package [`topiclongtable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/topiclongtable) seems to be apropriate for that, except that it does not accept the column designator X from the [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package. This column designator creates a paragraph-like column whose width automatically expands so that a declared width of the environment is filled.

Is there one solution to using the X column designator in a `topiclongtable`?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{topiclongtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{topiclongtable}{\linewidth}{|Fl|Tl|Tl|TX|}
  \Topic[Topic 1] & \Topic[Subtopic 1] & \Topic[Subsubtopic 1] & This is a long paragraph to be typeset in multiple lines, if possible. \\
  \Topic & \Topic & \Topic[Subsubtopic 2] & Bar \\
  \Topic & \Topic[Subtopic 1] & \Topic[Subsubtopic 2] & Baz \\
  \Topic[Topic 2] & \Topic[Subtopic 1] & \Topic[Subsubtopic 3] & Qux \\
  \Topic & \Topic[Subtopic 2] & \Topic[Subsubtopic 4] & Zod \\
  \Topic & \Topic & \Topic & Bop \\
\end{topiclongtable}

\end{document}
```

It does not work because the `longtable`, used in the implementation of `topiclongtable`, does not accept the column designator X, and the width of the table cannot be specified.

Comment: One shouldn't load the `longtable` and `tabularx` environments individually. Instead, do load the `xltabular` package, which combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` packages to provide an environment called `xltabular` which knows what to do with the `X` column type.

Comment: As per the manual prepend“F” to the first column specification and“T”to a  others. If you edit your question to add a MWE people will be able to help you better.

Comment: unrelated but you only need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if you have an old version of latex

Answer (score 3):

You could use a package like `xltabular`  that combines `longtable` and `tabularx` and then persuade this package to use it, but honestly it's not really worth it, it is simple to use the standard `tabular` `p` column.

First make a guess of the width say

```
\begin{topiclongtable}{|Fl|Tl|Tl|Tp{200pt}|}
```

Latex reports

```
Overfull \hbox (45.8892pt too wide) in alignment at lines 9--16
```

so subtract 46pt and use

```
\begin{topiclongtable}{|Fl|Tl|Tl|Tp{154pt}|}
```

This is essentially what `tabularx` would do, but more efficient as it's only done once as opposed to making latex do multiple settings of the table every time to find this width.

[image]